# Do the demons ever try to conquer Brahma loka or Shiva loka?

Tags: shiva, brahma, asuras, rakshasa

When Daitya Hiranyakashipu conquered the universe, he conquered up till Swarga.

> [Text 13](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/7/4/): O my dear King, Hiraṇyakaśipu was always drunk on strong-smelling wines and liquors, and therefore his coppery eyes were always rolling. Nonetheless, because he had powerfully executed great austerities in mystic yoga, although he was abominable, **all but the three principal demigods — Lord Brahmā, Lord Śiva and Lord Viṣṇu** — personally worshiped him to please him by bringing him various presentations with their own hands.

Have the demons ever successfully conquered Brahma loka or Shiva loka?

Comment: I do not think so. Vaikunth Loka, Satya Loka and Shiva loka are for people who are going to attain enlightenment due to either Bhakti towards Shiva/Vishnu or meditation and self knowledge.

Comment: title and body are contradictory.. u r looking for "ever try to conquer" or "ever successfully conquered" ?

Comment: @YDS Either one